# Wordpress: Home page redirects to posts page

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am using Polylang for translating my [website](http://www.emixis.com/). I have some problems managing the 'pretty' permalinks:

- in English (EN) - it looks ok;
- When switched to FR (same for NL)  - from Home page it redirects to the posts page, which now has the same url, as the one wanted for the homepage in French: www.emixis.com/fr/ <--- this pags should be homepage, but it shows posts..

For displaying posts I have created a page called News (in EN, FR and NL) and I have set in Settings/Reading that this is the posts page. And indeed it works ok www.emixis.com/fr/news/

So the main issue is that the homepages in FR/NL can not be accessed because their urls are "taken" from the posts page...

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem here ?
Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Have you managed to solve it ? Cz I am not able to see the issue that you described ..

Comment: Yes, I just posted an answer. Thank you anyway, Rohil_PHPBeginner!

Answer (score 0):

I think there you need to change **Reading Settings** from the wp-admin,

You need to select **static page** option and then select **Home page** from the given drop-down list.

I hope it will resolve your issue, let me know if it will not work!

Comment: Nope, this is not the problem, I have already set the static page to be my Home page (sorry I forgot to mention that).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and it turned out to be quite unexpected reason...

So Polylang uses two letter codes for most of the languages (in this case **fr** for French and **nl** for Dutch).

My homepages in French and Dutch have slugs respectively /fr and /nl. For some reason this was causing the confusion and Wordpress was redirecting from the French homepage to the french index (which in that case is the posts page in french)

I changed the two letter codes in the Settings of Polylang (Settings/Languages/Settings) and now all works OK and all pages seem to be at the right place...